# Convert Nested For Loops into a LINQ Expression

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop

Please consider the following code:

```
    private ISet<int> CalcSumsOfTwoNums(IEnumerable<int> nums) {
        ISet<int> iset = new HashSet<int>();
        var asArray = nums.ToArray();

        for (var i = 0; i < asArray.Length - 2; i++) {
            for (var j = i; j < asArray.Length - 1; j++) {
                var sum = asArray[i] + asArray[j];
                if (sum <= MAX) {
                    iset.Add(sum);
                }
            }
        }

        return iset;
    }
```

Does it make sense to convert the nested `for` loop syntax into a LINQ expression or LINQ dot notation? Is this one of those situations where the `for` loop syntax is more appropriate? My inclination is to say that the `for` loops are better here because I am dependent on the index position of the array as I am going through it to get to the resulting set.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what the loop actually does, to make it easier?

Comment: as far as i know Linq hast the performance of an regular loop

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - I think that the most important thing that I am trying to discover is that in the `for` loop syntax above the `i` and `j` variables holding the index of the array are the key to the calculation of the sum, and I don't understand how to translate that into a LINQ syntax. The values in `nums` can be arbitrary like 1 to 10. I return an `ISet` instead of an `IEnumerable` to guarantee that values returned are unique.

Comment: Why do you want to use LINQ for that in the first place? It's nice for some kind of operations for sure, but at the first glance I'd say this isn't one of them. And maybe it's intended but the last value of the array won't be used with the limits you have the in the for loops.

Comment: Your solution will be quicker then LINQ, because you can't start iteration from middle of collection with LINQ. Even using `Skip` extension method.

Comment: @WiiMaxx: LINQ usually has worse performance because of the lambda functions that are involved. They look easy but are actually quite complex in the implementation. It won't matter for all cases of courses.

Comment: @Dirk i just miss the **not** in my comment :o)

Comment: @Dirk - That is the very question that I want to answer... Is this a situation where a LINQ expression will buy you more than just readability? Based on the answers below, I think that it's pretty clear that the LINQ syntax is more clear than the Loop syntax, but there is a performance penalty. The `for` loop code runs on an average of 300 ms on my machine while the LINQ implementation by MarcinJuraszek runs on an average of 3 secs and the code from AppDeveloper takes an average of 8.5 secs to complete. This is fascinating!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static ISet<int> CalcSumsOfTwoNums2(IEnumerable<int> nums)
{
    // get List<int> from nums to get info about collection length
    var source = nums.ToList();

    // proper iteration
    var data = source.Take(source.Count - 1)
                     .SelectMany((e, ix) => source.Skip(ix)
                                                  .Take(source.Count - 1 - ix)
                                                  .Select(i => new { e, i }))
                     .Select(x => x.e + x.i)
                     .Where(x => x < MAX);

    // return HashSet instead of IEnumerable<int>
    return new HashSet<int>(data);
}
```

It returns the same results as your method. However, I would stay with your current solution. It would have better performance than LINQ.

Comment: There is one small mistake on the code above and that is on the last `Where` clause it should read `x <= MAX` instead of `x < MAX`

Comment: I am choosing this answer as the accepted one because MarcinJuraszek's algorithm avoids doing the extra work of calculating every sum twice. Additionally, this answer runs about 2.5 times faster, but not faster than the `for` loop syntax.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the Linq Below :

```
var asArray = nums.ToArray();
var result = (from n1 in asArray.Take(asArray.Length - 2)
              from n2 in asArray.Take(asArray.Length - 1)
              where n1 + n2 <= MAX
              select n1 + n2);

iset = new HashSet<int>(result);
```

it has the same output as your snippet does.

Comment: The inner loop still iterates from the beginning of that collection. The sample from question starts inner loop from actual position in outer loop: `var j = i`. Results are the same, but there is a couple unnecessary iterations in your solution.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - chk again pls!

Comment: The result is ok, because HashSet combines duplicates together :) However you're calculating every sum twice: as (i1, i2) and (i2, i1).